# Project : Log Analyzer

Tags: java, perl, nosql

I'm thinking of starting a log analyzer project for a product I'm supporting.

Does anyone have any idea how to begin?

Basically the logs come in a zip file and the log analyzer have to "unzip" it and look for key words. (Example bugs related to an exception and etc).

I believe majority of the code will surround rule base system where by certain rules will be trigger when a version of logs has been uploaded.

It should have some flexibility to allow user to add rules into it as issues are being discovered.

Any good book to read on this topic and etc?

Comment: I'd suggest have a look at elasticsearch/Kibana/Logstash.

Answer (score 0):

why inventing a wheel again when there is already some ( just change the color and add what u want to it).

maybe something like [chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/) or [lilith](http://lilith.huxhorn.de/).